# Run a command without making me wait

Tags: linux, shell, terminal, sh, calabash

I'm a newbie of Shell Script Linux.
I'm working on Automation testing with Android , so I'd like to run some shell script following as bellow:

1. Start recording screen by adb  ( cmd1.sh)
2. Do the scenario testing then Stop/Save recorded file  (cmd2.sh)

Unfortunately , when I run cmd1.sh I MUST wait 3 minute before cmd2.sh is run.
That means I can not record a video :sad:
Here is the my run command content:

**run.sh** file content:

> ./cmd1.sh $
>   ./cmd2.sh

**cmd1.sh** file content:

> adb shell screenrecord /sdcard/file.mp4

**cmd2.sh** file content:

> calabash-android run app.apk

Finally, I open terminal then run command :

> ./run.sh

Of course, video can not save because after cmd1.sh is finished, cmd2.sh is run !!!
Have anybody can help me in this point?
Thank you so much !

**@Jrican**  ***Updated***
Here is the manual step that I can play video recording.
 1. OPEN terminal A
 2. Run command 1 ( Start recording screen script )
 3. Open other terminal B then run a command 2
 4. After command 2 finished, go back to Terminal A then Ctrl C .
 5. Confirm video in /sdcard/file.mp4 that can play normally

I'm working on MAC OSX Yosemite 10.10.5

Comment: Will this work?$
./cmd1.sh &
./cmd2.sh

Comment: Thanks ! Let me try then update you soon !

Comment: @Jrican : I have tried it. But still does NOT work. 
Error :   
$: command not found

Comment: don't put the $ sign in front, that was just to represent the command prompt.

Comment: ./cmd1.sh & ./cmd2.sh

Comment: @Jrican : Thank you so much. It's working fine . You look like my Idol :)

Comment: @Jrican : Sorry, How can I kill/Stop cmd1 after cmd2 finished  ? 
I mean I want STOP recording video Before Save it...

Comment: "fg %1" will bring the first job to the foreground, can you stop it there? "kill %1" will kill the first job, but you probably don't want that.

Comment: Here is the process that I want : 
1. Starting recording by cmd1 => 2. Do the testing automation by cmd2 => (After finished cmd2) Stop cmd1 mean Stop recording ( Normally is Ctr+C) => Then save file record

Comment: try: "fg %1" then keys "ctrl+c"

Comment: @Jrican : Here is automation testing. I don't want to use 'Ctrl C' :Sad:
Please kindly to help me confirm this ? Thank

Comment: try: "kill -SIGINT %1", also I made this into an answer, see below.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91540/discussion-between-jrican-and-tokyoman).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easy Solution:
run.sh file content:

```
./cmd1.sh &          # run this command in the background
./cmd2.sh            # run this command to completion 
kill -SIGINT %1      # send the interrupt signal to the first command (ctrl+c)
```

Slightly more correct Solution:
run.sh file content:

```
./cmd1.sh &            # run this command in the background
recPID=$!              # save the PID for this process for later
./cmd2.sh              # run this command to completion 
kill -SIGINT $recPID   # send the interrupt signal to the first command (ctrl+c)
```

Comment: I'm confirming why I can not play video after save. 
I 'll update the other way that I can play video in question above .

Answer (score 1):

To run two commands simultaneously and then kill the first command's PID upon completion of the second command:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Run first command in background:
./cmd1.sh & PID="$!"

# Run second command:
./cmd2.sh

# Kill the first command:
kill "$PID"
```

Comment: I do NOT want to wait in here.   
cmd1 means starting recording. cmd2 means do testing case. 
Above all, I want to record a video.  
Hope you get my problem

Comment: I removed the time delay. Though i sense this still does not address your problem. I'll try installing those packages on my android and see if i can reproduce the use case.

Comment: Thank you . Jrican's answered is corrected. But I have another problem that I want to Kill/ Stop Cmd1 after Cmd 2 Finish ???

Comment: Edited so as to kill the first process upon completion of the second.

Comment: I have tried your command. My video still can not run. 
How can I check that I already killed exactly PID ? 
Because if I stop command 1 by CTR C , I can play video as normally. 
I think the problem come from can not kill cmd1 before Save file